# Listening to a Jewish broadcaster in the US after Shabbat ends in Israel

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, performance-entertainment, time-zone

Many baseball games (for example) take place Saturday afternoon in the US. This generally corresponds to beginning (or mostly taking place) after Shabbat ends in Israel. If the broadcaster of one of these games is Jewish, can you listen to the game?

It is still Shabbat for them, but not for you. They are not broadcasting specifically for your benefit.

Sports is *lav davka* here, it's just a common occurrence (and the one that's practical for me). It could equally apply to a talk show, or anything else being broadcast live.